# Select Value In Table Inside Of Modal And Populate The Form Outside Of The Modal?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, bootstrap-modal, jscript

This First Image Show The Empty Form and having 3 sample input and having their own name.

---

[image: Img1]

On This Second Image You Will See The Modal Having Table Inside, Each Of them has different name/data.

---

[image: Img1]

I want is, if i select 1 row in that table whether i filter or click second page, the form outside must be populated by data i select on table `<td>`.

**Here's my sample code:** [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/p9cLkh1d/)

---

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css"/>
     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <br>  <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Show Record</button>  <br>  <br>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="Hidden" name="ID" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name"  class="form-control">
       </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Bday</label>
      <input type="date" name="Bday"  class="form-control">
       </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Age</label>
      <input type="number" name="Age"  class="form-control">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit"  class="btn btn-success">
       </div>
    </form>
    
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table" id="example">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Bday</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name1</td>
                    <td>10-1-1997</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name2</td>
                    <td>9-1-1997</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name3</td>
                    <td>8-1-1997</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name4</td>
                    <td>7-1-1997</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name5</td>
                    <td>6-1-1997</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name6</td>
                    <td>10-1-1997</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name7</td>
                    <td>9-1-1997</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name8</td>
                    <td>8-1-1997</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name9</td>
                    <td>7-1-1997</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name10</td>
                    <td>6-1-1997</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name11</td>
                    <td>6-1-1997</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
     </div>
    
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    } );
    </script>
    </html>
```

I don't know  how should i pass the clicked value on modal to form.
Thanks in advance i hope someone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below steps in order to populate the values in the form:

1) Capture the table object created by datatable

```
var table= $('#example').DataTable();
```

2) Now capture the table body of your table

```
var tableBody = '#example tbody';
```

3) Add click event handler on the tbody

```
$(tableBody).on('click', 'tr', function () {
var cursor = table.row($(this).parents('tr'));//get the clicked row
var data=cursor.data();// this will give you the data in the current row.
});
```

4) Now set the data values in your form based on the data you have captured. For Ex.

```
$('form').find("input[name='name'][type='text']").val(data.name);
```

Do console the data before you find out the keys in order to get the value.
or check this
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9cLkh1d/1/) for working result

Comment: Hello, i think your answer is correct. can you add sample or jsfiddle to show the result ? its said `uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>`, `jQuery.Deferred exception: data is not defined ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: Make the var data variable inside click handler global. That is declare it outside the click handler. Or else write point 4 inside click handler so that var data is accessible.

Comment: I can’t see any image :(

Comment: @Franz Yes, also print data on console to check what keys you are getting and accordingly set the other two fields of the form as well.

Comment: i dont know why it didnt work on me, can u include the whole code and edit your answer , before i click check on your answer ?

Comment: Add your running code to fiddle and I will update it.

Comment: w8 @BALDEEP SINGH KWATRA,  
you are heaven sent.

Comment: @Franz I have updated all the code. Here is the updated fiddle  which is populating the value in the form. Please share and upvote Thanks :) https://jsfiddle.net/p9cLkh1d/1/